# Getting an unmodifiable MultiKeyMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm using a `MultiKeyMap` provided by `org.apache.commons.collections4.map`. I need to return an unmodifiable view of this map through the getter method, so that clients can't modify it. For java's in built map I could use `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` method, but for this specific map I couldn't find any similar method. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MultiKeyMap<K,V>` implements the interface `java.util.Map<MultiKey<? extends K>,V>`, you should have no problem wrapping your `MultiKeyMap` with `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`. You just may need to use a different way to access the elements: for each `get` call, you'll need to pass an explicitly created `MultiKey`, but that shouldn't be a major problem.

However, do you really want to do this? By returning an unmodifiable view of your field, you would be leaking implementation details of your class; that is, you'd be leaking the fact that it is implemented using a field from an Apache class. If you later wanted to changed it to use, e.g. Guava instead, then you'd have to go around finding all users of your class and changing them to call `get` using a different argument. So, instead of returning a collection field (albeit an unmodifiable view), consider adding getter methods for individual elements of the collection. I.e. you'd write `get(key1, key2)` etc. For more details see:

https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/EncapsulatedCollection.html

https://refactoring.guru/encapsulate-collection

Comment: Actually that's what I ended up doing. I found out it was never a use-case to return all elements in the map. Thanks for the suggestion.